# Twig: How to correctly chain two if-conditions where one condition contains the "not" keyword?

Tags: twig

I'm trying to write an `if` statement in twig that doesn't seem to be working.

```
{% if content.thumbnail_uri != '' and '/podcasts/' not in content.thumbnail_uri %}
```

The first statement before the `and` is working properly.

For the second statement I want to ensure `content.thumbnail_url` (which is a string/URI that is extracted from a JSON string) doesn't contain the sub-string `/podcasts/`.

How do i write this if-statement correctly in a twig template?

Comment: Should work as is. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/xfm1aa/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use braces to group your statements correctly.

The following syntax will work:

```
{% 
  if (content.thumbnail_uri is not empty)
  and ("/podcasts/" not in content.thumbnail_uri)
%}
```